# Comments aren't properly displaying under post (using jsonplaceholder)

Tags: javascript, html

When I'm clicking on comment icon, comments are displayed only on the first card. Also comments' appearance only changing on the first card. Everything else seems to be working fine. I want every card to show and delete its' own comment separately. You can see my issue with snippet code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a89a4ef5c6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>lab</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" id="btn" class="mt-3 mx-auto btn btn-primary">Get Posts</button>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 100px" class="row" id="cardDiv">
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    let ton = 0;
    let div = document.getElementById('cardDiv');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", getPosts);

    function getPosts(){
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((response)=>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((resp)=>{
           console.log(resp)
            resp.forEach(
                elem=>{
                    div.innerHTML += `
                       <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                           <div class="card-body">
                           <div>${elem.id}</div>
                               <h5 class="card-title">${elem.title}</h5>
                               <p class="card-text">${elem.body}</p>
                                <i id="myClick" onclick="showComments(${elem.id})" class="far fa-comment"></i>
                           <div class="zxc" id="hello"></div>
                         </div>
                       </div>`
                }
            )
        })
    }

    function showComments(q){
        let commentPlace = document.getElementById('hello');
        let inp = document.getElementById('myClick');

        if (inp.classList.contains("far")) {
            fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
                .then((resp)=>{
                    return resp.json();
                })
                .then((post)=>{
                        for (let index=0; index < post.length; index++){
                            if (post[ton].postId === q){
                                commentPlace.innerHTML += `<p>${post[ton].body}</p>`
                            }
                            ton = ton+1;
                        }
                        ton = 0;
                    }
                )
            inp.classList.remove("far");
            inp.classList.add("fas");

        }else {
            inp.classList.remove("fas");
            inp.classList.add("far");
            commentPlace.innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason your comments are not displayed properly is because you are creating the cards through a forloop which assigns every card the same id `hello` and `myClick`.

I have edited your code and it will work now -

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a89a4ef5c6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>lab</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <button type="button" id="btn" class="mt-3 mx-auto btn btn-primary">Get Posts</button>
    </div>
    <div style="padding-top: 100px" class="row" id="cardDiv">
    </div>
</div>

<script>

    let ton = 0;
    let div = document.getElementById('cardDiv');
    const btn = document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", getPosts);

    function getPosts(){
        fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts")
        .then((response)=>{
            return response.json();
        })
        .then((resp)=>{
           console.log(resp)
            resp.forEach(
                elem=>{
                    div.innerHTML += `
                       <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                           <div class="card-body">
                           <div>${elem.id}</div>
                               <h5 class="card-title">${elem.title}</h5>
                               <p class="card-text">${elem.body}</p>
                                <i id="myClick-${elem.id}" onclick="showComments(${elem.id})" class="far fa-comment"></i>
                           <div class="zxc" id="hello-${elem.id}"></div>
                         </div>
                       </div>`
                }
            )
        })
    }

    function showComments(q){
        let commentPlace = document.getElementById(`hello-${q}`);
        let inp = document.getElementById(`myClick-${q}`);

        if (inp.classList.contains("far")) {
            fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments")
                .then((resp)=>{
                    return resp.json();
                })
                .then((post)=>{
                        for (let index=0; index < post.length; index++){
                            if (post[ton].postId === q){
                                commentPlace.innerHTML += `<p>${post[ton].body}</p>`
                            }
                            ton = ton+1;
                        }
                        ton = 0;
                    }
                )
            inp.classList.remove("far");
            inp.classList.add("fas");

        }else {
            inp.classList.remove("fas");
            inp.classList.add("far");
            commentPlace.innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```